# Torch - repeat tensor like numpy repeat

Tags: lua, torch

I am trying to repeat a tensor in torch in two ways. For example repeating the tensor `{1,2,3,4}` 3 times both ways to yield;

```
{1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4}
{1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4}
```

There is a built in torch:repeatTensor function which will generate the first of the two (like `numpy.tile()`) but I can't find one for the latter (like `numpy.repeat()`). I'm sure that I could call sort on the first to give the second but I think this might be computationally expensive for larger arrays?

Thanks.

Comment: repeatTensor and expandAs are your friends.
https://github.com/torch/torch7/wiki/Torch-for-Numpy-users

Answer (score 22):

Try torch.repeat_interleave() method: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.repeat_interleave

```
>>> x = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3])
>>> x.repeat_interleave(2)
tensor([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3])
```

Comment: This should be the appropriate answer!

Answer (score 8):

Quoting https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-tile-a-tensor/13853 -

> ```
> z = torch.FloatTensor([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
> 1 2 3
> 4 5 6
> 7 8 9
> z.transpose(0,1).repeat(1,3).view(-1, 3).transpose(0,1)
> 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
> 4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6
> 7 7 7 8 8 8 9 9 9
> ```

This will give you a intuitive feel of how it works.

Answer (score 6):

```
a = torch.Tensor([1,2,3,4])
```

To get `[1., 2., 3., 4., 1., 2., 3., 4., 1., 2., 3., 4.]` we repeat the tensor thrice in the 1st dimension:

```
a.repeat(3)
```

To get `[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4]` we add a dimension to the tensor and repeat it thrice in the 2nd dimension to get a `4 x 3` tensor, which we can flatten.

```
b = a.reshape(4,1).repeat(1,3).flatten()
```

or

```
b = a.reshape(4,1).repeat(1,3).view(-1)
```

Comment: Care to explain your answer?

Comment: @AndréSchild My bad. Better now?

Comment: Does your answer not contain serious python syntax error? e.g. `a = torch.Tensor{1,2,3,4}` and `a:repeatTensor(3)`? I ran this and got syntax errors.

Comment: This was back in the days of Lua torch (http://torch.ch), not Pytorch :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic function that repeats elements in tensors.

```py
def repeat(tensor, dims):
    if len(dims) != len(tensor.shape):
        raise ValueError("The length of the second argument must equal the number of dimensions of the first.")
    for index, dim in enumerate(dims):
        repetition_vector = [1]*(len(dims)+1)
        repetition_vector[index+1] = dim
        new_tensor_shape = list(tensor.shape)
        new_tensor_shape[index] *= dim
        tensor = tensor.unsqueeze(index+1).repeat(repetition_vector).reshape(new_tensor_shape)
    return tensor
```

If you have

```
foo = tensor([[1, 2],
              [3, 4]])
```

By calling `repeat(foo, [2,1])` you get

```
tensor([[1, 2],
        [1, 2],
        [3, 4],
        [3, 4]])
```

So you duplicated every element along dimension 0 and left elements as they are on dimension 1.

Answer (score 1):

Use einops:

```
from einops import repeat

repeat(x, 'i -> (repeat i)', repeat=3)
# like {1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4}

repeat(x, 'i -> (i repeat)', repeat=3)
# like {1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4}
```

This code works identically for any framework (numpy, torch, tf, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

**Can you try something like:**

```
import torch as pt

#1 work as numpy tile

b = pt.arange(10)
print(b.repeat(3))

#2 work as numpy tile

b = pt.tensor(1).repeat(10).reshape(2,-1)
print(b)

#3 work as numpy repeat

t = pt.tensor([1,2,3])
t.repeat(2).reshape(2,-1).transpose(1,0).reshape(-1)
```